# The consumer isn't authorized to access - access token React and Magento 2

Tags: reactjs, magento, magento2

I'm trying to get data from Magento 2 but I got this error on the console

```
The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.", parameters: {…}, trace: '#0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-web…Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run()\n#16 {main}'}
```

I think I need to add an access token to get the data but I don't know how to add the token to my code

```
fetch("https:.....com/rest/V1/categories")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have assigned the correct admin user role for the admin user. And in that user role, you have given permission to access all nodes.

Go through once [this link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html).

Verify once user role and authentication token.

Or maybe your session (auth token) expires.

You can increase session lifetime as well.